# Subscribing to an event emitter returning undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to allow the user to delete an ingredient from a array of ingredients in their shopping list on my recipe app. I have created an event emitter which is fired when the user clicks the delete button. I subscribe to the event but the following error message is being presented: "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined".

The other problem I believe I will have is that 'ingredient' (which is the event data I get) is not a number. As I am using this in the splice method, I do not believe this will work. Hoping someone can help.

Here is the relevant html code:

```
<div *ngIf="ingredients.length > 1">
    <div class="shopping-list-container">
        <img src="https://i.ya-webdesign.com/images/shopping-cart-icon-png-1.png" class="shopping-cart-image" alt="shopping cart">
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients" class="shopping-list row">
                {{ ingredient.name }} - {{ ingredient.amount }}
                <img (click)="onDeleteItem(ingredient)" src="https://getdrawings.com/free-icon/delete-all-icon-63.png" alt="delete" class="delete-image">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the event emitter which is created in a .service file (I have only included the relevant bits here):

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})



  export class ShoppingListService {

   deleteItem = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>();

  }
```

here is the .component file (again I have only included what's relevant):

```
import { ShoppingListService } from './shopping-list.service';

export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {

ingredients: Ingredient[];

constructor(private shoppingListService: ShoppingListService) { }

ngOnInit() {

   this.shoppingListService.deleteItem.subscribe( 
      (ingredient: number) => {
        this.ingredients.splice(ingredient, 1);
      }
    );
  }

  onDeleteItem(ingredient) {
    this.shoppingListService.deleteItem.emit(ingredient)
  }

}

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an event emitter instead of a subject?

Comment: @KurtHamilton See comment below under Reza's answer

Comment: That's fair enough, but using EventEmitters like this is a misuse of their intended behaviour. And you can pretty much replace `EventEmitter` here with `Subject` and it should work - call `.next()` instead of `.emit()` though. You're already using the observable behaviour from the `EventEmitter` (against the advice of the Angular team).

Comment: Ok thanks Kurt, I'll give this a go

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `EventEmitter` in services, it's only for `components`

Instead you need to use `Observable`s and `BehaviorSubject/Subject`s as below

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ShoppingListService { 
  itemDeleted : Subject<Ingredient> = new Subject<Ingredient>();
  private itemDeleted$: Observable<Ingredient> = this.itemDeleted.asObservable();

  deleteItem(item:Ingredient) {
    this.itemDeleted.next(item);
  }

}
```

in your component

```
private unsubcribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject<Any>();

ngOnInit() {

   this.shoppingListService.itemDeleted
   .pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubcribeAll)
    )
   .subscribe((ingredient: Ingredient) => {
        // this.ingredients.splice(ingredient, 1);
   });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribeAll.next();
  this.unsubscribeAll.complete();
}

onDeleteItem(ingredient) {
    this.shoppingListService.deleteItem(ingredient);
}

}
```

`unsubcribeAll` in above code is used to prevent memory leak and unsubscribing from observable

### Solution 2

if your components are in same hierarchy you don't need services to inform of actions.

for example

recipe.component

```
<section>
   <app-ingredient-list [ingredients]="recipeIngredients" (itemDeleted)="onItemDeleted($event)"></app-ingredient-list>
</section>
```

receipe.component.ts

```
  onItemDeleted(item:Ingredient) {
     // do what is needed here
  }
```

ingredient-list.component.ts

```
  @Output() itemDeleted: EventEmitter<Ingredient> = new EventEmitter<Ingredient>();

  onDeleteButtonClick(item: Ingredient) {
    this.itemDeleted.emit(item);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is appreciated. I am in the process of learning angular (as you can probably tell) and I haven't reached the part of the course which goes into observable's yet. I am simply creating a first project using what I have learnt so far and will then move onto observable's (I find this is the best way I learn as it allows me to digest information more easily). Therefore, I would need to stick to just using event emitters at the moment. The injectable was there by the way, I just forgot to include it in my OP (I have edited my OP now).

Comment: @JohnDev no worries, the other thing is if you are learning you don't need that complexity, this way (having service to notify) is applicable when your component are no in same hierarchy and you want to notify other components from the other modules

Comment: @JohnDev see my updated answer for simpler solution

Comment: Thanks again Reza. This wouldn't work for me unfortunately but I think this is a good time for to start learning how to use observable's!